# swift: Bundle.main.path returns nil

Tags: swift, xcode

i created a folder in my assets called "json" into there i dragged&dropped a file called code.json from the finder. Now i want to open the file but

```
Bundle.main.path(forResource: "code", ofType: "json", inDirectory: "json")
```

just returns `nil`.

I also tried to put it in the assets without the subfolder and using following way

```
Bundle.main.path(forResource: "code", ofType: "json")
```

with the same result.

Can anyone help me? What am i doing wrong?

Comment: Does the `.app` bundle contain the file you want to access? Is the file part of the `Copy Files` build phase?

Comment: Do you mean myProject->Build Phases->Copy Bundle Resources? No it wasnt. i just tried adding it by clicken on the +, then "Add Other", navigated to my assets folder and further to the file added it with "Copy items if needed" but i got the same result.

Comment: I'd recommend drag&drop from the xcode project navigator instead. Also after you build go to the build folder and check if the json file actually got deployed to the app bundle.

Answer (score 7):

You need to make the folder reference when you drag it to xcode , it's color is blue not yellow

[image]

//

[image]

Answer (score 4):

It is clear from your question that you are trying to add the code.json file in **Assets.xcassets** and trying to access it's path with Bundle.main.path(forResource: ), which will always returns nil, because Assets.xcassets is present in Bundle and then your file exists in it.

Try adding the files directly to the project, as suggested in previous answer,  approach is right, Bundle.main.path(forResource: "code", ofType: "json")